# Start a NodeJS Server Through XCode

Tags: xcode, node.js, terminal, localhost

I would like to start a server on a localhost at the same time that my application in XCode is launched.

I have a NodeJS application that works and starts when I run `node server.js` in Terminal, but I would like to start the server through XCode once that application is launched. Is that possible? How would I do so?

Comment: Any help here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that runs when XCode starts. You could use that script to start your Node.js app. Here is a reference to the script XCode looks for:

http://books.google.com/books?id=rYjv9MKZ3JwC&pg=PA518&lpg=PA518&dq=startup+scripts+for+XCode&source=bl&ots=of70AW0hr9&sig=-_RVl1gmndRa99ETTev0ZcERwJE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vNAxU9SgB87GoATwu4HACQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=startup%20scripts%20for%20XCode&f=false

and here is a reference to automating Terminal tasks in Applescript:

http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/10/25/automating-terminal-tasks-on-osx

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I assume you have `server.js` in "Copy bundle resources". Otherwise, provide valid `jsPath`

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *nodePath; // node path; usually /usr/local/bin/node
NSString *jsPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"server" ofType:@"js"];

[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:nodePath arguments:@[jsPath]];
```

Another thing to try would be copying `node` file to app bundle. So `NSString *nodePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"node" ofType:nil];`. And if works, it will run your .js on machines without node installed - *although i haven't tested it*.